# How can i override a scope route with a named route in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces, scope

I have this scope:

```
scope ":section", :section => /[a-zA-Z_]+/ do
 resources :case_studies, :promotions, :events
end
```

URL example: :section/case_studies

And i have a named scope:

```
namespace :admin do
 resources :case_studies, :promotions, :events
end
```

URL example: admin/case_studies

The problem is the admin case studies, promotions, and events are registering the "admin" namespace portion as a section variable. Is there a way to limit the scope more or have admin take precedence over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are executed top-down in your `routes.rb` file. If you make sure they're in this order:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :case_studies, :promotions, :events
end

scope ":section", :section => /[a-zA-Z_]+/ do
  resources :case_studies, :promotions, :events
end
```

Then the `admin` routes should take precedent over your `section` routes.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. It's weird, that was the first thing i tried earlier and it didn't work, but now it does.

Answer (score 0):

for precedence move the admin namespace higher up in your routes.rb file